# Initialization of Array Objects With Parenthesis in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, array-initialization, object-initialization

Here there is a class with two private fields x and y;

```
class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int = 1,int = 1);
    void move(int, int);
    void print()
    {
        cout << "X = " << x << ", Y = " << y << endl;
    }
};
```

When initialization the array of Point objects as below, the output is ok;

```
Point array1[] = { (10), (20), { 30, 40 } };
```

Output;

```
First array
X = 10, Y = 1
X = 20, Y = 1
X = 30, Y = 40
```

However, if we initilize the Point array as below, the output is weird;

```
Point array2[] = { (10), (20), (30, 40) };
```

Output;

```
Second array
X = 10, Y = 1
X = 20, Y = 1
X = 40, Y = 1
```

Why (30,40) is not working for initialization of Point object?

Here is the complete test code;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int = 1,int = 1);
    void move(int, int);
    void print()
    {
        cout << "X = " << x << ", Y = " << y << endl;
    }
};

Point::Point(int x, int y)
{
    cout << "..::Two Parameter Constructor is invoked::..\n";
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

void Point::move(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

int main()
{
    // Point array1[] = { Point(10), Point(20), Point(30, 40) };
    // Use parenthesis for object array initialization;
    Point array1[] = { (10), (20), { 30, 40 } };    // curly bracket used for two parameter
    Point array2[] = { (10), (20), (30, 40) };      // paranthesis used for all objects

    cout << "First array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        array1[i].print();

    cout << "Second array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        array2[i].print();

    return 0;
}
```

And the complete output of test code;

```
..::Two Parameter Constructor is invoked::..
..::Two Parameter Constructor is invoked::..
..::Two Parameter Constructor is invoked::..
..::Two Parameter Constructor is invoked::..
..::Two Parameter Constructor is invoked::..
..::Two Parameter Constructor is invoked::..
First array
X = 10, Y = 1
X = 20, Y = 1
X = 30, Y = 40
Second array
X = 10, Y = 1
X = 20, Y = 1
X = 40, Y = 1
```

Comment: Probably because it takes `(30, 40)` as an expression with a comma operator that evaluates to the single number `40`.

Comment: @owacoder no probably about it. this is exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why (30, 40) is not working:

stating `(30, 40)` is not the same as stating `{30, 40}` nor stating `(30)` is the same with `{30}`.

`(30, 40)` is a sequence of expressions (in this case integral literals), separated by [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which evaluates to the last expression (i.e., `40`). Whereas, `{30, 40}` in the context used is an [aggregate initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Answer (score 5):

The compiler takes `(30, 40)` as an expression with a comma operator that evaluates to the single number `40`. You should turn on compiler warnings to find that the `30` is discarded.

Parenthesized expressions in array initializers are taken as expressions, not constructor invocations. You can call the constructor explicitly to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

The parenathese in your code are causing you confusion.  When you write `(10)` this does not mean call a constructor with a parameter of 10.  `(10)` becomes 10 and you can se that with

```
Point array1[] = { 10, 20, { 30, 40 } };
```

So for the second array

```
(30, 40)
```

Uses the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) so

```
 { 10, 20, (30, 40) }
```

Becomes

```
 { 10, 20, 40 }
```

If you want to call the two parameter constrcutor you will have to bracket it like the first example or explicitly call the constructor

```
{ 10, 20, Point(30, 40) }
```